# Add a link to Literature.SE as a choice for migration in an off-topic close vote

Tags: discussion, status-declined, migration

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38773/top-10-fallacies-love-is-a-fallacy) was closed as off-topic with 3 downvotes.  Four minutes later, the poster manually re-asked it [on Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/441/top-10-fallacies-love-is-a-fallacy) and got 2 upvotes along with an answer.  Should we consider allowing migration to Literature.SE from here?

Comment: I say it should be a valid option because Literature.SE seems to welcome questions of analysis. For example, [this question](http://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/454/role-and-significance-of-molly-grue) asks for analysis of a book--questions which are expressly off-topic here.

Comment: once literature has been in beta for a few months longer, I might be open to that sort of like writers

Comment: @Jeff: three months have passed, is it yet time to allow migration to Literature.SE? Or does it need more beta time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site is still in beta phase. The rule is that it's not allowed the migration to sites that are still in beta phase; the only users who can migrate to a beta site are moderators, who can migrate a question to every SE site.

About allowing to migrate a question to literature.SE, I am in favor, when the site is past its beta phase, and provided there are enough asked questions that could be migrated to that site. If the questions that should be migrated there are too few, then flagging a question for moderator attention should be sufficient to do the task.
Consider also that the main rule is, "Don't migrate crap." This would mean that, even having the opportunity, few question would probably be migrated.

Comment: Writers.SE is a beta, and we can vote to migrate there, can't we?

Comment: That is the exception that confirms the rule. The general rule is that the migration to a beta site is not the normal migration path for an SE site.

Comment: Tsk. "Exception that *proves* (tests) the rule" :)

Comment: I translated the proverb from the Latin: _exceptio probat regulam in casibus non exceptis_ ("The exception confirms the rule in the cases not excepted"). `:-)`

Comment: @FumbleFingers up vote from me, for your comment. I wish I could think of some pithy expression, slightly opaque, that concurred with you, but none comes to mind.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: On investigation I'm surprised to discover the expression did in fact have that meaning. But apart from facetious usage where it doesn't really mean anything at all, I've never heard it used with any meaning other than *tests/strains/puts the spotlight on*. Somewhat similar to *"hard cases make bad law"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know the proverb is "the exception proves the rule"; the fact my first language is Italian, where the proverb is _l'eccezione che **conferma** la regola_, doesn't avoid I use _confirms_ instead of _proves_. `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Well I suppose there's nothing to stop the meanings diverging between languages and/or times. It's mostly said facetiously in my experience anyway. The special scope of *confirming there is a general rule* is obviously useful for interpreting the intent of legalese, but not for many other contexts.

Comment: Interesting. 
The way I learned it, it means that noticing an exception proves that there must be some rule for it to be an exception to; whether we know the rule or not consciously, it exists. Also, the exception **tests** the rule (another sense of _probāre_).

Oh, and by the way, Linguistics.SE has gone three days without anybody asking a new question, so they might be ready for some more questions.

Answer (score 5):

No, we shouldn't allow migration, because unfortunately [Literature.SE is closing](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/literature-is-closing):

> As mentioned in [the recent blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/), I must reluctantly announce that we'll be shutting this site down on Friday, May 4th, 2012. While a fine topic, progress here has been slow for some time now, and it simply does not appear that literature (in the general sense) has a strong enough following on our network to support the site long-term.

Comment: Although we possibly could allow individual questions to be migrated, if relevant... but that wasn't the question here, so you get my +1.

Comment: @FeralOink I don't think we could, since all the questions are going into a data dump

Comment: @simchona: Correct. However, until 4th May, we can [scavenge](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/literature-is-closing-what-questions-should-we-migrate-here) some of *their* good questions over here.