# Voting off topic questions that belong on Linguistics.SE

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a link to Literature.SE as a choice for migration in an off-topic close vote](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/add-a-link-to-literature-se-as-a-choice-for-migration-in-an-off-topic-close-vote)

When a voting to close a question as off topic, we're given the option to say it belongs here on meta or [Writers.SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/).

[image: Off topic dialog]

Sometimes questions asked at EL&U are better suited for [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/). Can also we have the option to migrate over there?

Comment: Kiamlaluno's answer to the linked question does fully answer this one (both sites are still in beta), but I would just like to note that this was a request to add Linguistics.se as a migration option and the dupe question is about Literature.se as a migration option, which is *not* the same site ;)